# twig using variables as hash key

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to use the `path` function dynamically? With variables as parameters?

`{{ path(nav.url, { nav.param_name : nav.param_value }) }}`

Because if I try to use that code I am getting:

```
A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). 
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." 
("punctuation" expected with value ":")
```

I know by passing 'hardcoded' the `param_name` will work... like this:

`{{ path('nav.url', { 'id' : nav.param_value }) }}`

However I need to pass the 3 value dynamically

Comment: As an alternative you can pass a `params` array and use it like this: `{{ path(nav.url, nav.params) }}`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Twig book says you have to enclose expressions in parentheses to use them as keys, so maybe this will work:

```
{{ path(nav.url, { (nav.param_name) : nav.param_value }) }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals